# whereBetween passing array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

Hi I have query where I want to pass an array to `whereBetween` query.

for example I have an array which looks like this

```
Array
(
    [product_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31337
            [1] => 31366
        )

    [lands] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 23
        )

)
```

Now I want search those `product_id` which are between  [0] => 31337 and [1] => 31366 and same goes to land I want to find the lands where Between [0] => 12 and  [1] => 23

now say I have a variable `$filters` which has the this above array in it and I pass it like this to the query like below.

```
public function scopeDynamicInBetweenFilter($query, $filters)
    {
        if(!empty($filters)){
            return $query->whereBetween($filters);
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

It gives me an error

> Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereBetween(), 1 passed and at least 2 expected

it does like this at

```
Builder->whereBetween('product_id' => array('31337', '31366'))->whereBetween('lands' => array('12', '23'))
```

what could be done to achieve this.

Comment: show your code where you are calling this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to loop through the filters and apply it to the query

```
public function scopeDynamicInBetweenFilter($query, $filters)
{
    if(! empty($filters)) {
        if (is_array($filters)) {
            foreach ($filters as $key => $value) {
                $query->whereBetween($key, $value);
            }
        }
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!empty($filters)){
    return $query->whereBetween('product_id', $filters['product_id'])->whereBetween('lands', $filters['lands']);
}
```